# comparing elapsed times between multiple threads and multiple processes with concurrent.futures

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to understand the difference between threads and processes in python by running the code below.

```
from numba import jit
import random
import time
import concurrent.futures

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def monte_carlo_pi(nsamples):
    acc = 0
    for i in range(nsamples):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        if (x**2 + y**2) < 1.0:
            acc += 1
    return 4.0 * acc / nsamples

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nparl = 6   # Number of parallel processes/threads
    print("Number of parallel processes/threads: ", nparl)
    n_in = int(4e6) # input for monte_carlo_pi
    _ = monte_carlo_pi(n_in) #use once for jit
    print('********************************')
    print('1 - SERIAL')
    tini = time.perf_counter()
    out1 = [None]*nparl
    for i in range(nparl):
        out1[i] = monte_carlo_pi(n_in)
    print("pi = ", sum(out1)/nparl)
    tend = time.perf_counter()
    print("Time elapsed: ", tend-tini)
    print('***************************************')
    print('2 - MULTI THREAD WITH CONCURRENT.FUTURES')
    tini = time.perf_counter() 
    thread = [None]*nparl
    out2 = [None]*nparl
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for i in range(nparl):
            thread[i] = executor.submit(monte_carlo_pi, n_in)
            out2[i]=thread[i].result()
        print("pi = ", sum(out2)/nparl)
        tend = time.perf_counter()
    print("Time elapsed: ", tend-tini)
    print('***************************************')
    print('3 - MULTI PROCESSES WITH CONCURRENT.FUTURES')
    tini = time.perf_counter() 
    process = [None]*nparl
    out3 = [None]*nparl
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for i in range(nparl):
            process[i] = executor.submit(monte_carlo_pi, n_in)
            out3[i]=process[i].result()
        print("pi = ", sum(out3)/nparl)
        tend = time.perf_counter()
        print("Time elapsed: ", tend-tini)
        print('***************************************')
```

I took the function `monte_carlo_pi()`, which calculates stochastically an approximation of , from the numba site. I'm using Spyder (Python 3.8) on a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10850H CPU @ 2.70GHz with 6 cores with Windows 10.

I'm a bit puzzled by the output:

```
Number of parallel processes/threads:  6
********************************
1 - SERIAL
pi =  3.14171
Time elapsed:  0.22061820000089938
***************************************
2 - MULTI THREAD WITH CONCURRENT.FUTURES
pi =  3.1416696666666666
Time elapsed:  0.22931740000058198
***************************************
3 - MULTI PROCESSES WITH CONCURRENT.FUTURES
pi =  3.141372833333333
Time elapsed:  3.4144941000013205
***************************************
```

I'm wondering if somebody can help me answering a few of questions.

1. Why the elapsed time is almost the same between the serial (case 1) and the multithread case (case 2)? I thought that, by using `nogil=True,` each thread would have used a different core
2. Why the multi process run (case 3) is significantly slower? My understanding is that multiprocessors should be penalized by I/O operations, but here it does not look like we have may I/O operations.
3. I'm wondering if the code is parallelized at all. If I run the same code with

```
nparl = 3   # Number of parallel processes/threads
```

instead of `nparl = 6` the elapsed times scale proportionally for case 1 and 2 and less than proportionally for case 3

```
Number of parallel processes/threads:  3
********************************
1 - SERIAL
pi =  3.1418706666666663
Time elapsed:  0.1084104000001389
***************************************
2 - MULTI THREAD WITH CONCURRENT.FUTURES
pi =  3.142234666666667
Time elapsed:  0.10978269999941404
***************************************
3 - MULTI PROCESSES WITH CONCURRENT.FUTURES
pi =  3.1407256666666665
Time elapsed:  2.4338965000006283
***************************************
```

I'm sure I'm missing something very fundamental here and I'm wondering if somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're not running this concurrently but just sequentially looping one by one. Schedule the jobs first and then wait for the results:

```
$ diff -u test.py.orig test.py
--- test.py.orig    2021-04-04 16:09:30.986336091 +0100
+++ test.py 2021-04-04 16:08:56.097523834 +0100
@@ -35,7 +35,8 @@
     with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
         for i in range(nparl):
             thread[i] = executor.submit(monte_carlo_pi, n_in)
-            out2[i]=thread[i].result()
+            # out2[i]=thread[i].result()
+        out2 = [i.result() for i in thread]
         print("pi = ", sum(out2)/nparl)
         tend = time.perf_counter()
     print("Time elapsed: ", tend-tini)
@@ -47,7 +48,8 @@
     with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
         for i in range(nparl):
             process[i] = executor.submit(monte_carlo_pi, n_in)
-            out3[i]=process[i].result()
+            # out3[i]=process[i].result()
+        out3 = [i.result() for i in process]
         print("pi = ", sum(out3)/nparl)
         tend = time.perf_counter()
         print("Time elapsed: ", tend-tini)
```

Btw there is no need to initialize an array (list) variable in Python so something like this should do the trick:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    threads = [executor.submit(monte_carlo_pi, n_in) for _ in range(nparl)]
    out2 = [t.result() for t in threads]
```

Comment: I see, it makes sense now. Thank you very much. From the Task Manager, I can see all cores are utilized now. One more question if I may. The output (with `nparl = 6`) now gives
(1) SERIAL Time = 0.2176, (2) THREAD Time = 0.0754 and (3) PROCESSES Time = 1.9124. Does it make sense that (3)>(2)?

Comment: I meant (3)>(1). By the way, this happens only with `@jit`. Without, it's (1)=(2)>(3), as expected

Comment: Spawning a new process is an expensive operation in itself and thus adds to the overhead of creating and executing multiple tasks, especially on Windows where the parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process. So `(3)>(1)` could be the case with a very low `nparl` value. I guess doing this computation in a loop with 6 iteration can be less expensive than creating 6 processes, copying the parent's address space etc. As you noticed, this is only the case when you use `numba` with JIT compilation of course. When you increase the `nparl` you should see the expected difference.

Comment: Thanks again; very instructive